# Marionette Master + Mana Tokens (Gold, Treasure, etc.)

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The card [Marionette Master](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=marionette%20master) states:

> Whenever an artifact you control is put into a graveyard from the battlefield, target opponent loses life equal to Marionette Master’s power.

Are Ixalan Treasure tokens, Tezzerat Ethereum Cells, etc. considered "put into graveyard" when tapped for mana and sacrificed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

"Artifact" means "artifact permanent", which means "artifact card or token on the battlefield".

> 109.2. If a spell or ability uses a description of an object that includes a card type or subtype, but doesn’t include the word “card,” “spell,” “source,” or “scheme,” it means a permanent of that card type or subtype on the battlefield.
>
> 110.1. A permanent is a card or token on the battlefield. [...]

To sacrifice a permanent, it is moved to the graveyard.

> 701.15a To sacrifice a permanent, its controller moves it from the battlefield directly to its owner’s graveyard. [...]

In fact, you can't sacrifice an object unless it's a permanent you control.

> 701.15a [...] A player can’t sacrifice something that isn’t a permanent, or something that’s a permanent he or she doesn’t control. [..]

So if you have sacrificed an artifact token, you have put an artifact you control into a graveyard from the battlefield, so your Marionette Master's triggered ability will trigger.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, tokens will trigger "dies"/"goes to the graveyard" triggers when they are destroyed, sacrifices, &c.

The relevant section of the MTG comprehensive rules is this one:

> 110.5f A token that’s in a zone other than the battlefield ceases to exist. This is a state-based action; see rule 704. (Note that if a token changes zones, applicable triggered abilities will trigger before the token ceases to exist.)

Since the comp rules can be difficult to understand in full, the card's page in Gatherer includes a ruling about this situation — see [Marionette Master](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMarionette%20Master%5d):

> 9/20/2016     Artifact tokens that are sacrificed or destroyed are put into their owner’s graveyard before ceasing to exist. If you controlled the token, Marionette Master’s last ability will trigger.